# Android GoogleAnalytics2 not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm not receiving any GoogleAnalytics meesage in LogCat.
The only messages for analytics are:

```
05-16 13:09:18.148: W/GAV2(2110): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
05-16 13:09:18.167: I/GAV2(2110): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
```

I have used this article:
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/integrating-google-analytics-sdk-v2-with-android/

I haven't seen 'hit'in log cat as other users report in their questions. I've put sendEvent to be sure that at leas one record is created for send - logcat reports : "nothing to send...."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurs on one device only.One user suggested reason: SPACE in sendpage and sendevent are reason to broke DB on test device. After clear all - problem solved!